# Liet-Kynes's imperial name

Tags: dune

In Dune (the book), Liet-Kynes is a kind of spiritual leader of the Fremen. The Fremen call him Liet, and the imperials (including Harkonnen and Atreides) call him Dr Kynes. Only the Fremen know that Liet is the same person as Dr Kynes.

The appendix tells about how Liet's imperial role as planetologist was essentially inherited from his father Pardot Kynes. The father's name was Pardot Kynes: but **what was the son's name**? Apparently he does not use "Liet" as his name among the imperials. So is his name just "Dr Kynes" with no first name? Seems odd since his father did use a first name.

Herbert often writes the name as "Liet-Kynes" rather than "Liet Kynes", which to me also suggests that Liet is not supposed to be a first name in the traditional sense.

(I'm hoping for an answer in Frank Herbert's books- I'm not sure if this is addressed in Brian Herbert's books also, but I'm interested in that too.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It appears to be **Weichih**, according to [*Dune: House Harkonnen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune:_House_Harkonnen). Certainly that's the name that he's introduced to visiting nobility as.

> “Thank you for inviting us, Lady Fenring,” Kynes’s son said, looking
> at Margot. The Planetologist had introduced the young man as Weichih,
> a name that meant “beloved.” She could see a resemblance to the
> father, but while the older Kynes had a dreaminess in his eyes, this
> Weichih bore a hardness caused by growing up on Arrakis.
>
> ...
>
> Luxury is for the noble-born, Liet,” Pardot Kynes said as the
> groundcar trundled across the uneven ground. Here, in privacy, he
> could use his son’s secret sietch name, rather than Weichih, the name
> reserved for outsiders. “On this planet you must instantly become
> aware of your own surroundings, and remain alert at all times. If you
> fail to learn this lesson, you won’t live long.”
>
> ...
>
> “The Emperor is not aware of any ecological plans.” Liet withheld his true Fremen identity, said nothing about his father, and introduced himself by his other appellation, “My name is . . . Weichih.”

Comment: Note that this book (and none others in the series, nor the Dune Encyclopedia or games) contains the sole references to this name.

Comment: It's not you I hate Dune prequels...I hate what I became because of you